# can't make bootstrap 3 look good in print

Tags: css, printing, twitter-bootstrap-3, print-css

I need to print with bootstrap 3 but I can not make it look good, any ideas how to fix it?

this is how it should be

[image]

currently looks like this

[image]

this is my code

```
    <div class="row page-header">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-2"><img alt="'.$row['codigo'].'" src="barcode.php?codetype=Code39&size=40&text='.$row['codigo'].'" />'.'<div class="small">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$row["nombre"].'</div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That's the same image.

Comment: yeah I don't see any differences. Could you elaborate?

Comment: my mistake, is fixed now

Answer (score 0):

You would need to show your markup for those barcodez for us to actually try and fix it, but it would require editing the print media query styles:

```
@media print {
  /* style sheet for print goes here */
}
```

Comment: ergo, you need to post your relevant css.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @media print {
        .wrapper{
        overflow:hidden; /*make sure the wrapper has no dimension*/

        margin-bottom:5px;
    }

    .item{
        float:left; 
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
        background:none;
        margin:5px;
        text-align:center;
    }

    }
```